# Agregar dinámicamente una clase al primer td de mi tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla que no se cuantas columnas tiene ni cuantas filas, necesito agregar una clase al primer y segundo td de mi tabla dinámicamente con js

Necesito que quede de la sigiuente forma

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td class="claseaqui">Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="claseaqui">Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="claseaqui">Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
   <td>Prueba</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola @Miguel. La pregunta está un poco confusa. Si quiere agregar una clase al primer y segundo `td`, ¿cómo es que agregas una clase a cada primer `td`? Debes especificar si es al primero y segundo `td` por cada fila o simplemente, se le aplique a los primeros campos (`td`) de la tabla. Lo que observo es que quieres colocar un primer campo (`td`) por cada fila de la tabla, ¿cierto?

Comment: Yo entiendo, que quiere agregar al primer td de todos los tr una clase con js, asi. no?

Comment: Efectivamente Jose justo eso

Comment: Quieres agregar al primer y segundo `td` de todos tus `tr`?

Comment: Hola Juan, dentro de todos los tr que tiene la tabla al primer td de ese tr quiero agregale una clase

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín si es asi, que tiene que ver el segundo? Ya que dices "*primer y segundo td*"

Comment: Cierto joer tengo la cabeza ya... necesito que el primero y segundo TD de cada TR tenga una clase

Comment: investiga y prueba con algo como $('td:first-child').each(function() {
    console.log('first td') // aqui el modificador de tu propiedad clase.;
});

Comment: @MiguelZarate creo que es mejor `eq` sin `each`, ya que quiere solo el primero y segundo

Comment: si solo es para que se de una idea de como puede encontrar una solucion, esta en el proceso de aprender por eso no escribi una respuesta

Comment: @MiguelÁngelMartín mira esto y prueba para resolverlo [eq-selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: @MiguelZarate, puede escribir una respuesta. En ella puedes explicar el problema.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. aunque creo que es mejor que el OP ponga la respuesta el mismo, como dice MiguelZarete, esta en proceso de aprender

Comment: La razón por la que pregunta es porque tiene alguna duda.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM., de acuerdo, pero se le está guiando para que lo intente primero. Si algo falla, entonces sí viene la respuesta.

Comment: @Triby, vale, lo tomaré en cuenta.

Comment: MiguelÁngelMartín, trata de leer primero sobre el tema de los selectores. Los mismos selectores que funcionan para las hojas de estilos funcionan para JavaScript. Consulta [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_CSS#pseudoelementos).

Comment: En el caso de que no logres conseguir una solución habrá personas acá dispuesta a ayudarte. Si logras encontrar la solución, publique una respuesta de cómo lo solucionaste. Te apoyaremos en ello.

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo, no sabía que se podian usar los selectores de esa manera, muchas gracias a todos por vuiestras respuestas

Comment: Excelente @MiguelÁngelMartín. No olvides publicar una respuesta de cómo encontraste la solución. Será bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('table td:nth-child(1)').addClass("sticky-table");
$('table td:nth-child(2)').addClass("sticky-table-2");
```

Tan sencillo como hacer esto, seleccionamos la columna 1 y la columna 2, le agrego dos clases diferentes a cada columna